# Select the Data from token input

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

One of the field has token input and it has got multiple values. its a single select field, once we choose one particular value from that field and submit and then re-open the same form, we have some logic which will clear that field, but before clearing we are storing the value in one of the variable and after it gets cleared, we write it back, problem is we have used normal jquery to write the value, which is not working. can any one tell me how to write it back.

### Below is structure of token input

```
<div>
    <ul class="token-input-list-ap">
        <li class="token-input-token-ap"></li>
        <li class="token-input-input-token-ap">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="token-input-idlov17" style="outline: none; width: 30px; display: none;">
            <tester style="position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; width: auto; font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; white-space: nowrap;"></tester>
        </li>
     </ul>

     <input type="text" id="idlov17" name="ONSITE_lov" class="reportField  fieldsXtraLength" value="" placeholder="Find by name or email" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried, and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Archer : I actually dont have the code, the actual token input code comes from our platform. i just tried to write using $('#idlov17').val(value); is there any specific syntax to write ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is specific sytax. I believe you're after:

```
$('#idlov17').tokenInput("add", {id: XXX, name: value});
```

Whether id and name are the two JS object attribures you need depends on how you've initiated your tokenInput. But that's the default.

Comment: add will add new valus rite ? but i want to choose from list.

Comment: `Add` will add them to the field as a token, not the dropdown search results. I'm unsure from your explanation where you are reloading and recreating the TokenInput, but I think you need either this, or `prePopulate`. If you are able to create a jsFiddle, I could have a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

If its regarding to retain a multiple values in the tokenInput field, this plugin provides flexibility to retain multiple tokens in an input field. For example, the plugin provides an attribute 'tokenLimit' where we can set it to 2 or more (for multiple tokens).

In addition, in order to prepopulate the tokeninput field with some values, you may use 'prePopulate' attribute as well.

Here is the demo for the same: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#pre-populated

I hope this might help you.